# Spring JPA Native Query not giving result set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The Below query is not returning any result from DB when running through spring boot JPA CrudRepository class.

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT *,(6371 * acos(cos( radians((?2)) ) * cos( radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians((?3))) + sin(radians((?2))) * sin(radians(latitude)))) as distance FROM Table_Name where service_id =(?1) HAVING distance <3 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 5;")
      List<Respone> findNearByPlacesByService(Integer service, float lat,
          float longg);
```

While checking the hibernate sql query logs on console it seems that the parameters are not getting injected in the query. There is no exception in logs.

**Console Logs:**

```
Hibernate: SELECT *,(6371 * acos(cos( radians((?)) ) * cos( radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians((?))) + sin(radians((?))) * sin(radians(latitude)))) as distance FROM merchant_outlet_services where service_id =(?) HAVING distance <3 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: When `Hibernate` logs, it shows the `?` symbols instead of actual values. My guess is that it's actually passing them into the query. How do you know the result is incorrect?

Comment: The result set is empty when I run it thru application. But when I run the same query on DB directly it is returning result.

Comment: Two questions; What are `latitude` and `longitude` in the query? Are you  copying/pasting the exact query and substituting the variables that are going into the query to the DB?

Comment: @Dovmo - My Bad, Was pointing to wrong db instance.

Comment: At least it's figured out!